# Default value for abstract class in constructor

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have a class whose constructor looks like

```
class foo
{
public:
foo(Base const& b);
private:
derived c;
Base const& b_;
};
```

I would like c to be the default value for the constructor like

```
foo(Base const& b = c):b_(b)
```

However I get an error saying :
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

How can I set a default value of a specific derived class for b?

Comment: Non-static data members can't be used as default arguments.

Comment: This is not posssible in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight up prohibited. From n3337:

> §8.3.6/9 Similarly, a non-static member shall not be used in a default
>   argument, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the
>   *id-expression* of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1).

In other words, for this to work, `c` must be `static` since no object is required to access a static data member.

```
class foo
{
public:
foo(Base const& b = c);
private:
static derived c;
Base const& b_;
};
```